# How to get Content of Remote HTML page

Tags: php, html

I want to get remote html contents that on "li" that with a spacific Class name and Children of em using divs.

My remote content is Like this

> <ul>
>
> <li class="user">
>
> > <div class="name">My Name 1</div>
> >
> > <div class="rep">20</div>
>
> </li>
>
> <li class="user">
>
> > <div class="name">My Name 2</div>
> >
> > <div class="rep">23</div>
>
> </li>
>
> <li class="user">
>
> > <div class="name">My Name 3</div>
> >
> > <div class="rep">40</div>
>
> </li>
>
> </ul>

After get their data it must be like this.

> [My Name 1,20]
>
> [My Name 2,23]
>
> [My Name 3,40]

Thanks.

Sorry for the My Poor English

Note : Have more content than this on remote page.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use CURL to read the remote URL to fetch the HTML.

```
$url = "http://www.example.com";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Then use [PHP's DOM object model](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse the HTML.

For example to fetch all `<h1>` tags from the source,

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML( $output);

//get all H1
$items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h1');

//display all H1 text
 for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++)
        echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br/>";
```