# get title of cntent of site in php

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, curl

I wrote a code to curl the website content like facebook and google+ ,

```
 $html = file_get_contents_curl($url);

    if ($html) {
//parsing begins here:
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);
        $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

//get and display what you need:
        $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++) {
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if ($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
                $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        }
```

........

I got the title of page by `$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;` but I need to fetch the title of news or content title(my url always not news websites) ,I dont want to restrict myself to some site, I want get the title of content of websites.

as example 
return  **Guantanamo must close during Obama's term - Russian Foreign Ministry** in http://rt.com/news/guantanamo-closure-russia-dolgov-245/

**France to shed ‘Amélie’ image after 50 years of China ties**  in http://www.france24.com/en/20140127-france-seeks-shed-amelie-image-50-years-after-opening-ties-with-china/

**Defining Moments: Capturing our changing world**  in http://edition.cnn.com/2013/05/01/world/defining-moments/index.html?hpt=hp_bn3

I know usual way is fetch `H1` or `H2` tags but I need fetch title of some sites that not implement title of news with those and use `<div>` tag
as example

http://www.mehrnews.com/detail/News/2222373

**update I test this [link](http://farhangipress.ir/detail/News/6753) in google+ and some another url that the headline is not in `<h?>` tags, and google return Title correctly, any body know how it work?**

Comment: Do you mean the title of the page as it appears in the browser's title bar, or the headline of the page? The one you can get by grabbing the `<title>` element, and I imagine that the other is probably the first `<h1>` tag in the page, though that's less reliable

Comment: `I need to fetch the title of news or content title(my url always not news websites) ,I dont want to restrict myself to some site, I want get the title of content of websites.` The title on different sites may be in different places, you can't guarantee its location. Although it'll most likely be in the `h1` tag on each page, so just extract it from there?

Comment: @andrewsi  I means the headline

Comment: @MLeFevre I think maybe exists good way, because facebook and g+ do this work correctly

Comment: @zhilevan looks like this other question is doing what you're after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733876/how-to-get-content-ot-remote-html-page

Comment: @zhilevan no, they don't just take any random site and parse it perfectly. I assure you, there's no magic way of doing that. You can only take a good guess unless the sites tell you exactly what to expect.

Comment: @MLeFevre I update a question look it again plz

Comment: @m59 google plus done it correctly , how ?

Comment: @zhilevan I don't know what you're talking about. Do you mean when you  post a link in a comment?

Comment: @zhilevan the way they do it accurately is they use the `title` meta tag. All 4 websites you linked have the title meta tag as is the correct practice. You asked how to do it otherwise (which means guessing) and I showed you. Your question seems to be about a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @m59 , no, go to google+ and in `Share what's new...`  insert one of link that headline is in <`div>` tags ,see what I mean, the google plus get headline correctly

Comment: @m59 look this link `http://www.mehrnews.com/detail/News/2222373` I  inspect html element I dont see any title meta tag that exactly be headline of news !!!

Comment: @zhilevan I just tested that out in Google+ and it pulls EXACTLY what is in the `<title>` tag into the post. Every site you linked is displaying the title according to the `title` tag.

Comment: @m59 I test it right know , and it return me title tag,my client told me that it return correctly and when I test some link it return correctly(but I am not sure those didn't have `<h1>` tags) , You right ,thanks for your attention and replies. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just note that the correct and reliable way is to use the `<title>` tag. As you asked how you could get the title from other elements, my answer will deal with that.

I don't think there will be any completely reliable way of doing this, but you could have your script take a good guess about what the title is.

The titles you want from each link you posted share a common pattern:

1. The title is within an `<h1>` tag.
2. The h1 tag of the title is the first title on the page that contains ONLY text.

Therefore, a reliable script for those examples would find all the `<h1>` tags on the page, then consider the "title" to be the first one that contains only text (no nested html elements).

As you are now adding more links in comments - don't expect an answer that will work for everything. The best anyone can do is inspect the elements, search through the page source and try to find a pattern for identifying the titles. For the links in your post, I demonstrated this. If you want to find titles that are displayed other way, you'll have to keep adding in checks for each scenario and hope for the best.

Comment: yes, I think but in most of time, use css to big the title instead using `<H?>` tags .

Comment: @zhilevan no, most of the time they are using the `h1` tag. It's beneficial for the website owner to do it that way. Chances are, if the website is using `css to big` the main title instead of placing it in an `h1` tag, it's a website not worth mentioning.

Comment: @MLeFevre see this , the title of news is with `<div>` tag :http://www.mehrnews.com/detail/News/2222373

Comment: @zhilevan Literally in the websites you linked in your question, that's what the titles are in. They are the first <h1> tags on the page that only contain text. If you wanted a more specific answer, you should include the relevant links in your post. It's unfair to keep adding demands.

Comment: @zhilevan It's probably an unfair remark, but I believe that's an example one of a website not worth wasting your time on. @m59's answer is correct, *good* websites will keep to conventions and make use of the `h1` tag or within `<title>`.

Comment: @MLeFevre I agree with you , but my client insist do it in some sites that when when I check them they are not implement title by `h1`, but he tell me how facebook and google+ fetch them correctly?