# Create a Personalized web search Application based on user profile interests

Tags: php, search, user-interface, web-applications, web

I am created a personalized search web application .I will create a signup,login and user will fill in his interests based on that i have a doubt in search

I only want to use PHP and JAVA Script alone.

1)After redirecting to that specific search page from login, when i type a specific keyword in that,all i need is ,I need to display results in that domain/web application by fetching the results from search engines.the results should be web content articles,image,video,news.

My doubts is how can i get the feeds from search engine to get displayed in my application such that the keyword which is provoked to search in the search tab should refer to match the user interests which is stored in the database based on this,it should provide the results.

I hope you friends understood the problem statement of this application.

Please help me solve this problem and if any code/book related to this,please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a well written question so I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. I interpret the problem as this:

1. You want a website that registers users with specified interests
2. You want those users to see tabulated results based on their interests (with the results being lifted from search engines).

The above being a correct interpretation, I would suggest you use something like the "curl" function, mentioned previously on Stackoverflow:
[How to get Content ot Remote HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733876/how-to-get-content-ot-remote-html-page)

In the above example, the URL specified would (in your case) contain the search engine string. Say you were searching for "bricks in china", then your url string that would be passed to the curl function, would be "https://www.google.co.zw/search?q=bricks+in+china&oq=bricks+in+china"

Another good example of tackling this problem (outside of the Stackoverflow community) is presented here: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-download

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much .Hayden Eastwood .your answer is very much helpful to me and i started trying to work on it.One last question is ,how can i invoke the cURL in a php webpage, while hitting a search button how to implement the curl code in the PHP web page so that i can display search engine results in my web page .thanks in advance.please help me

Comment: I would suggest you use a form. When the user clicks on the form's submit button to do a search, you can send the content to the curl function. A good explanation of how to read form information is over here: http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-tutorial.html. Let me know if you need more help :)