# How can I download all the content of this URL and get json data?

Tags: php, json

In php,

how can I download the content of this url into a json variable?
url = http://www.pinnaclesports.com/League/Soccer/Serie+A/1/Lines.aspx

Here is my code:

```
<?php

  include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

  $serieaURL = "http://www.pinnaclesports.com/League/Soccer/Serie+A/1/Lines.aspx";

  $serieaData = file_get_contents($serieaURL);
  $json = json_encode($serieaData);

  echo $json;
?>
```

All I get with this is: "\r\n\r\n\r\n

I have no idea of what this means, even googling that leaves me with doubts.

Where am I going wrong here?

Ty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733876/how-to-get-content-ot-remote-html-page

Comment: That page doesn't appear to be JSON...it's just html, css and javascript.  Are you wanting to collect the data from that page and form it into a JSON object?

Comment: Hi jiY. yes, that is want I want to do. But if it is only html, should I not get a list of links with my lines of code?